# Why is my Time Picker MUI not working in React project?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello i have a react and rails project .Im trying to style my react project.Im stuck with the MUI component Time and Date picker whenever I try implementing the time pickerI get a weird error.I want to somehow style it and use the update request to update the stuff.

```
EditReservationForm.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

This is the error occuring in line 106.I think the problem is it cannot detect the value
Pls take a look at my code.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./stylingfolder/EditReservation.css";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";

import * as React from 'react';

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';

const ColorButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
  backgroundColor: purple[500],
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: purple[700],
  },
}));

function EditReservationForm({ reservation, onUpdateReservation }) {
  const { name, date, time, num, contact, occasion } = reservation;
  const [updateName, setUpdatedName] = useState(name);
  const [updateDate, setUpdatedDate] = useState(date);
  const [updateTime, setUpdatedTime] = useState(time);
  const [updateNum, setUpdatedNum] = useState(num);
  const [updateContact, setUpdatedContact] = useState(contact);
  const [updateOccasion, setUpdatedOccasion] = useState(occasion);

  function handleEditClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`/reservations/${reservation.id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: updateName,
        date: updateDate,
        time: updateTime,
        num: updateNum,
        contact: updateContact,
        occasion: updateOccasion,
      }),
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((updatedReservation) => {
        onUpdateReservation(updatedReservation);
      });
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Box
        component="form"
        sx={{
          "& > :not(style)": { m: 1 },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleEditClick}
      >
        <h2>Modify Reservation</h2>
        {/* <form onSubmit={handleEditClick}  > */}
     
        <FormControl>
       
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Name</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            type="text"
            // id="email"
            id="email"
            value={updateName}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedName(e.target.value)}
            label="Name"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />

        <FormControl>
        
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Date</InputLabel>
          
          <OutlinedInput
            type="date"
            // id="email"
            id="date"
            value={updateDate}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedDate(e.target.value)}
            label="Date"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <TimePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={updateTime}
        onChange={(e) => setUpdatedTime(e.target.value)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
          {/* <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Time</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            type="time"
            name="time"
            id="time"
            value={updateTime}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedTime(e.target.value)}
            
          /> */}
       
    
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">No. of Guests</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            type="number"
            name="num"
            value={updateNum}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedNum(e.target.value)}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Contact</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            type="tel"
            name="contact"
            value={updateContact}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedContact(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="contact"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Occasion</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            type="text"
            name="occasion"
            value={updateOccasion}
            onChange={(e) => setUpdatedOccasion(e.target.value)}
          />
        </FormControl>

        <Stack paddingLeft={15} direction="row" id="loginbutton">
          <ColorButton variant="contained" type="submit">
            {" "}
            Update Reservation
          </ColorButton>
        </Stack>
        {/* </form> */}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
export default EditReservationForm;

``
Is there any other way this could work????or why is it not working?.When I remove the time picker and use the normal form input to put in the time it works properly .Error is caused only by this time picker.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
onChange={(e) => setUpdatedNum(e.target.value)}
```

to

```
onChange={(val) => setUpdatedNum(val)}
```

because [according to the TimePicker API](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/time-picker/#props) `onChange` function returns `value` instead of `event` unlike [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props).

Comment: Ahmet can you figure out the prob in this form as well its designed a little different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73677582/why-is-my-date-and-time-input-not-working/73677634?noredirect=1#comment130105602_73677634

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer to it in a while.